# jQuery parallax image misbehaving on first page load only

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I'm using parallax jQuery (Ian Lunn) plugin on the section of the site [here](http://logicon.no-ip.org/#section-parallax). It works great on subsequent refreshes, but on the first page load (i.e. when the background image is not cached) the parallax image is not aligned properly so the section appears white. If the user clears cache and then refreshes the problem happens again.

Is there a way I can fix this?

**EDIT**

My investigations so far seem to show the problem is intimately linked the image slider above. The parallax jquery needs to calculate the initial distance of the div element to be 'parallaxed' from the top, it calls this `firstTop`. The problem is that on an (uncached) page load the slider section has greater height than it ends up eventually having (possibly it's as if all the slides were stacked vertically). This in turn causes `firstTop` to be greater than it really should be...I'm not sure why the jQuery `$` doesn't cause the parallax script to wait until the dust has settled.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait till your image is loaded. Have you tried using 
`$( document ).ready( your function here )`?

Comment: Yes I already use that, the init script looks like: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){$.localScroll({});$('#section-parallax').parallax("50%", 0.5);});`

Comment: Ah, it seems that `$(window).load();` actually does the trick...(since needs images themselves not just DOM, which is what `ready()` waits for). Thanks for putting me in the right direction.